# How to do this lookup more elegantly in Python and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cursor, python, fetchall

I have a bunch of files in a directory named with **nameid_cityid.txt**, nameid and cityid being the ids of name **(integer(10))** and city **(integer(10))** in **mydata** table.

While the following solution works, I am doing type conversions since fetchall fetches 'L' and the file name tuple of nameid, cityid are strings,..

If you can suggest a pythonic or more elegant way of doing the same, that will be awesome, for me and the communtiy!

**What I am trying to achieve :**
Find those files from a directory that don't have a record in the database and then do something with that file, like parse/move/delete it.

**MySQL table mydata :**

```
nameid  cityid
15633   45632
2354    76894
```

**Python :**

```
for pdffile in os.listdir(filepath):
    cityid, nameid = pdffile.strip('.txt').split('_')[0], pdffile.strip('.txt').split('_')[1]    
    cursor.execute("select cityid, nameid from mydata")
    alreadyparsed = cursor.fetchall()
    targetvalues = ((str(cityid), str(nameid)) for cityid, nameid in alreadyparsed)
    if (int(cityid), int(nameid)) in alreadyparsed:
        print cityid, nameid, "Found"
    else:
        print cityid, nameid, "Not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a set for quick and easy testing:

```
cursor.execute("select CONCAT(nameid, '_', cityid, '.txt') from mydata")
present = set([r[0] for r in cursor])

for pdffile in os.listdir(filepath):
    nameid, cityid = map(int, pdffile.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('_'))
    print nameid, cityid,
    print "Found" if pdffile in present else "Not found"
```

First, I've pulled the query outside of the filename loop; no point in querying the same set of rows each time.

Secondly, I'll let MySQL generate filenames for me using `CONCAT` for ease of collecting the information into a set.

Thirdly, because we now have a set of filenames, testing each individual filename against the set is a simple `pdffile in present` test.

And finally, I've simplified your filename splitting logic to one line.

Now, if all you want is a set of filenames that are not present yet in the database (rather than enumerate which ones are and which ones are not), just use a set operation:

```
cursor.execute("select CONCAT(nameid, '_', cityid, '.txt') from mydata")
present = set([r[0] for r in cursor])

for pdffile in (set(os.listdir(filepath)) - present):
    nameid, cityid = map(int, pdffile.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('_'))
    print nameid, cityid, "Found"
```

Here we use the [`.difference` operation (with the `-` operator)](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) to remove all the filenames for which there are already rows in the database, in one simple operation.

Comment: I like the set based approach. I won't even have to do this 'nameid, cityid = map(int, pdffile.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('_'))' since we already have the desired list of files (since the existing ones are subtracted already). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could perform the concatenation in SQL, which will return a string:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nameid, '_', cityid, '.txt') FROM mydata
```

Comment: And iterate through each file in the directory to see which one isn't found in the table by matching the .txt file? I am trying to do it in the least number of iterations. I will time them and see which one takes less time I guess. Thank you!

Comment: @ThinkCode: Sorry, which are you trying to do - find files for which there is no database record, or vice versa?

Comment: Find files which don't exist in the database.

Comment: @ThinkCode: Perhaps build a single query `SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE (nameid, cityid) NOT IN ((15633,45632), (2354,76894), etc)`?

Comment: I am trying to see if a file doesn't exist in the database and then parse that file. So, I think I should do the opposite - find if a file exists in the database and if not, then parse it. Like you said, I can also construct a list of all files in the directory and match it against the database list. I can then open the resulting file directly and parse it.

Comment: @ThinkCode: the approach in my previous comment will give you a list of all the files you need to parse.  You would build it by iterating over the directory.

Comment: SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE (nameid, cityid) NOT IN ((15633,45632), (2354,76894), etc) - It should be the other way around cos' the files I am looking for shouldn't be in the file_directory_list.